# how can I write all the video and audio frames?

Tags: matlab, video-processing

My problem with the writing function is how can I write all the video frames and audio?
Because the step function writes only the last frame.
What loop condition am I using that enables me to write all frames and audio?

```
 readObject = vision.VideoFileReader('video_001.avi', 'AudioOutputPort',true);

writeObject = vision.VideoFileWriter('video17.avi', 'FileFormat','avi', 'AudioInputPort',true, 'FrameRate',readObject.info.VideoFrameRate, 'Quality',90);
writeObject.AudioInputPort=true;

while ~isDone(readObject)
    [frame, audio] = step(readObject); %[frame, audio] = avi();
end
  step(writeObject,frame, audio); %mp4(frame, audio);

release(readObject);
release(writeObject);
```

I want to make a loop to ***read*** and another loop separate to ***write***
How do I do that?
I appreciate any help for me...